# How can I make an emoji a command prefix with discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that's specific to a server with all the emojis as prefixes. My issue is, the bot doesn't respond to the emoji. Here's my code:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=':AtlantaFalcons:,' ':BaltimoreRavens')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the full id of the emoji sending `\:emoji:` in discord, you'll get something like `<:emojiname:99999999999>`

The copy paste that and put it in the `bot(command_prefix)` option